# Update android application with expansion file on Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, apk-expansion-files

I have an existing application on **PLAY STORE** with 1.5 GBs of data hosted on and downloadable from an external server.
After installing the application I am asking the user to download the data and set the path for it in the application.

Now I want to integrate the Expansion file mechanism in this application.
My questions are:

1. Is it possible to update the application with the Expansion File mechanism in which New users are able to download the data through the expansion file and existing users (after updating apk from the Play Store) don't need to download the expansion file again and can continue with the old data?
2. This is the paid application which is using GOOGLE Licensing as well; so if the above is not possible and if it's needed to upload a new application with a different package name and unpublishing the current application, then how to maintain existing users' (old application) Licensing?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Monika,he aint talking about that.An expansion file is not included in the apk.

Comment: @Monika, There is expansion file mechanism offered by play store it self to avoid using external server for applications using a large dataset (more than 50 MBs)

Comment: @ParikhVaibhav i hvnt implemented that yet .. so not sure abt this question but yes i can personally give a try abt this issue

Comment: @Monika ok thanks , let community know your findings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither is possible:

- Re 1: Google Play usually downloads the expansion file right along with the APK.
- Re 2: Apps can only verify their own license not the license of other apps using Google's License Verification Library.

Comment: Yes you are true @hans , it is not possible , thank you for answering , I just forget to update.

Comment: I have a query, if you can answer it would be very helpful for me. Currently i have expansion file on my apk, now i want to update my app, so if existing users update the app,do they need to download the expansion files again or google delete the existing expansion files??